# ORACLE stored procedure issues

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have created a stored procedure with one input paramter and a cursor to get result

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_STORED_PROC2
    (DISEASEID IN varchar2, stock2_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN stock2_cursor FOR
       SELECT DISTINCT 
           B.*, INITCAP(B.SYMPTOM_NAME) SYMPTOM_DESCRIPTION_NEW
       FROM 
           SYMPTOM_GLCL_DISEASE_LINK A, SYMPTOM_MASTER B
       WHERE 
           A.SYMPTOM_ID = B.SYMPTOM_ID
           AND A.DISEASE_ID IN DISEASEID;
END;
```

I want to pass 3 diseaseid in that input parameter, how to do that?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty hack could be passing concatenated ids via DISEASEID parameter (eg. `12,245,2532`) and then using `LIKE` operator for comparison (last line in query):

```
AND ',' || DISEASEID || ',' LIKE '%,' || A.DISEASE_ID || ',%';
```

But be aware that this is not an optimal solution (regarding speed, best practices...).